# Access GeoJSON from GitHub in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am new to JSON, GitHub, and Leaflet.

I am trying to create a simple application which will render my points which are in GeoJSON up on GitHub.

From everything I have read this should work.  Here is what I have so far but I do not see my points displayed.

What am I missing?

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/boehnert/GeoJson/master/coolPlaces.geojson"   type="text/javascript" > </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
 <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([29.7628, -95.3831], 10);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'examples.map-i875mjb7'
    }).addTo(map);

    var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("coolPlaces.geojson");       
    geojsonLayer.addTo(map);    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Github supports [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), you can use [jQuery's getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) or a micro-library like [corslite](https://github.com/mapbox/corslite) to grab your geojson without altering it. Here's a working example using `$.getJSON()` (notice that I took out your script tag referencing your geojson file):

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([29.7628, -95.3831], 10);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'examples.map-i875mjb7'
        }).addTo(map);

        $.getJSON("https://rawgit.com/boehnert/GeoJson/master/coolPlaces.geojson", function(response) {
            console.log("response", response);
            var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(response);
            geojsonLayer.addTo(map);    
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your github file cannot just contain a value; it must define a variable that will be defined when the file is included as javascript.

```
var geojsonFeature = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

....
};
```

Then you can use this variable as an input to your GeoJSON layer

```
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature);
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

UPDATE:
This is a method to use if you want to include coolPlaces.geojson as a script (like your question suggests).
However, as suggested by @Derek Swingley, you can also use an ajax call $.getJSON to get the json data as is (but this is because github supports CORS)

Comment: This isn't necessary. Github supports CORS so you can do a GET to grab the geojson with something like jQuery's getJSON() or a micro-lib like corslite.